# Let $G$ be a group such that $|G| =81$, $P$ be a set such that $|P|=98$ . Prove that $|P^G| = 3k+2$ with $k$ an integer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group such that $|G| =81$, $P$ be a set such that $|P|=98$. Prove that $|P^G| =  3k+2$ with $k$ an integer, where  $|P^G|$ is the set of elements of $|P|$ that are fixed by every element of $G$

**My attempt:**

Note that $G$ is a $p$-group, because $|G|=3^4$.

Moreover, we know that ${\rm Orb}_P(x)$ divide  $|G|$, in other words, $|{\rm Orb}_P(x)|$ must be a positive integer power of $3$ or $3^0$.

But $|{\rm Orb}_P(x)|$ must divide $|P|$ then $|{\rm Orb}_P(x)|=1$ for all $x \in P$

Here I'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Comment: It is not true that $\lvert Orb_P(x) \rvert$ must divide $\lvert P \rvert$. For example, $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ can act nontrivially on a set with $3$ elements by swapping two of them.

Comment: By the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem, the size of the orbit must divide the order of the group,  not necessarily the size of the set.

Answer (score 2):

An important piece of information that is missing from your setup: $G$ acts on the set $P$!

Anyway, like you said, each orbit must have cardinality $1$, $3$, $9$, $27$, or $81$. Also, $P$ is the disjoint union of its orbits. So, letting $a, b, c, d, e$ be the numbers of orders of the aforementioned cardinalities, we have

$$a + 3b + 9c + 27d + 81e = 98.$$

Also note that (by definition) $a = \lvert P^G \vert$. Can you use this to show that $\lvert P^G \rvert = 3k+2$ for some integer $k$?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see $a + 3b + 9c + 27d + 81e = 98.$ is the sum of the cardinalities of the orbitals.  I think i must use the  orbit-stabilizer theorem but i don't have very clear how...

Comment: @rcoder If $3b + 9c + 27d + 81e = 3(b+3c+9d+27e) = 98 - a$, then $98 \equiv a$  $\mod 3$.

Answer (score 0):

For any $G$-set, $P$, the orbit equation reads:
$$|P|=\left|P^G\right|+\sum_i\frac{|G|}{\left|\operatorname{Stab}(p_i)\right|}\tag 1$$
where $\operatorname{Stab}(p_i)\lneq G$, for every $i$. In your case, $|G|=3^4$, so $3$ divides $\sum_i\frac{|G|}{\left|\operatorname{Stab}(p_i)\right|}$. Therefore, from $(1)$:
$$98\equiv \left|P^G\right|\pmod 3\tag 2$$
namely:
$$2\equiv |P^G|\pmod 3 \tag 3$$